# Why is barefeet not a word?

Tags: adjectives, compounds

The question might seem absurd, but I am curious as to why ['barefeet'](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=barefeet) is not a valid English word.

Why is it 'barefoot' and not 'barefeet'?

Comment: foot is singular; feet, plural.  In compound nouns, the noun constituent is usually singular. E.g., bedroom (not bedsroom), rainfall, hanger-on etc.

Comment: "Barefoot" (or sometimes 'barefooted") is an adjective or adverb (it is used as both). There are other modifiers of a similar type such as "open-handed", "red-handed", "wide-eyed". "bareheaded" and "long-legged" in which the root nouns are also singular. We only have one head each but most of us have two hands and two eyes. It is characteristic of English that such modifiers use the singular form of the nouns which they incorporate.

Comment: @RamPillai - *hangers-on* is perfectly valid, and in fact I hear it more often than the singular *hanger-on*.